# pandas pivot_table parameters

Tags: python, pandas

For all of the parameters we can pass in to pivot_table, I don't understand what do parameters columns and values for. Take below codes for example, I am asked to construct a pivot table for DataFrame medals (Olympic medals won by countries in the past 10 years) and aggregated by count. Hope my question makes sense and thanks in advance.

```
medal_counts = pd.pivot_table(medals,index='Edition',values='Athlete',columns='NOC',aggfunc='count')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you want to know the difference between the `values` and `columns` parameters of `pivot_table`.

You can think of them this way:

- `values`: which column do you want to aggregate? Since you are applying a count, this translates to *what do you want to count*? In your example, you are counting *Athletes*.
- `columns`: which columns shall your resulting pivot table have? As you are counting Athletes, by what means do you want to count them? In your example, it will count *Athletes* for each *NOC*.

I hope this clarified it. Otherwise, you can always look at the documentation of [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). It also has a couple of examples that should help understand the functionality.

Comment: This is extremely clear and helpful. A lot of thanks!!

Comment: No worries. Please don't forget to accept and upvote the answer if your question is sufficiently answered.